# PHP actions in ratio

Tags: php

I have 3 options, and they have to happen in a particular ratio.
Out of 10 times, this is the ratio:

- 8x Option 1
- 1x Option 2
- 1x Option 3

Right now I have the following:

```
if (rand(8,10)) {
    option1();
} elseif (rand(1,10)) {
    option2();
} elseif (rand(1,10)) {
    option3();
}
```

But this gets option 1 way more than 8 times. Option 2 never occurs and option 3 rarely.

So, what is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with something like this.

```
$roll = rand(1,10);   
if ($roll == 1) {
    option2();
} elseif ($roll == 2) {
    option3();
} else {
    option1();
}
```

If random number is 1 (10% of the time), option 2.

If random number is 2 (10% of the time), option 3.

If random number is anything else (80% of the time), option 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = rand() / getrandmax();
if ($r <= 0.8) {
  option1();
} elseif ($r <= 0.9) {
  option2();
} else {
  option3();
}
```

Comment: @cmmi this will not maintain the exact ratio that priktop wants.

Comment: Thanks, it works better than my version, bit it seems that option3 never occurs? i've done 25 tests but no option 3 :(

Comment: @Alec could you specify why this will not work as requested? I am wondering. 0 <= $r <= 1, so in 80% of the requests $r will be <= 0.8

Comment: @Alec I just did a little benchmark. The distirbution is similar, no difference using the 0-1 approach or the rand(1,10) one. But interestingly the 0-1 approach seems to be faster then the 1-10 approach. Although the differences are minor.

Comment: @cmmi priktop wants the probability to be strictly enforced. So in a set of 10 outcomes, you want 8 of option1, 1 of option2 and 1 of option3. from the question atleast, it appears that he only wants the order randomized.

Comment: @Alec I must addmit I cannot follow your argumentation. What do you mean by strictly enforced? To secure that in each set of 10 one sample is of a special kind you have to check each round whether this kind was already produced or not and depending on this result you must choose what to do next (if it already exists you must prevent it to appear again). That's a lot different then the approach priktop apparently searched for.

Comment: @cmmi say if he wants that in every set of 10, the outcomes should be in the exact ratio but the order should be randomized, my method will work. After re-reading the question, am not sure if thats what he wants.

Answer (score -2):

No, this is not the right way. You can use something like:

```
<?php

// Store in DB use of options 1, 2 and 3
//  field     value
// -----------------
//  options1   0
//  options2   0
//  options3   0

// If $options1 = 8, $options2= 1 and $options3 = 1, then clear all values from DB

$random = rand(1,3);

if ($random == 1) {
  if ($options1 < 9) { option1(); } else { // tryagain; }
} elseif (
...


// update DB with new value for used option
```

Sorry the code is slightly messed up (the if part) but I guess you can understand. Let me know if you need the whole code.

Comment: Whats the db good for? Probability usually doesnt (and never should) take care of any previous, or upcoming event. Therefore this is a wrong approach.

Comment: @KingCrunch if you want the ratio to be strictly enforced and only the order randomized you need a db to store the outcome. did you even read the code?